# How to clean copper(II) sulfate crystals from sulfuric acid?

Tags: home-experiment, ionic-compounds, purification

I am going to prepare copper(II) sulfate by electrolysis with sulfuric acid for crystal growing.

How would I separate the copper(II) sulfate from the sulfuric acid left over from the electrolysis process in solution?

I think, one way would be to make copper(II) oxide and mix it with the solution so that I get more copper(II) sulfate out of the solution by using left over acid. Then separating copper oxide would be easy.

Comment: This seems like a [homework](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange) question. We ‎have a policy which states that you should show your thoughts and/or efforts into solving the ‎problem. It'll make us certain that we aren't doing your homework for you. Otherwise, this ‎question may get closed.

Comment: Well, this is for my own safety not a homework.  I plan to grow copper sulfate crystals. But I have doubts that I could properly clean them by household items.

Comment: Crystals do not contain acid. Small leftovers of acid won't be a problem for crystal growth.

Comment: They are wet at first. Not sure how well sulfuric acid evaporates.

Comment: It doesn't, you need to rinse them, BTW what you want to do  electrolysis for?

Comment: @Mithoron I will make copper(II) sulfate by electrolysis.

Comment: I got that the first time... You're oxidating metallic Cu in the presence of diluted H2SO4?

Comment: Yes. Both electrodes will be made out of copper wire.

Comment: I doubt it's a good idea

Comment: Using those electrodes or making this salt in general?